# Use of GetObject call to run vLookup without opening file

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide !

I am attempting to complete a series of "vlookup" function calls across ~150 files from a single workbook WITHOUT having to open each file.

I have attempted to write a function (inserted below) that returns the value of the lookup to a cell and as inputs it has the filename and lookup params

However the file is not closing. Instead it remains as a hidden file. The .close in the instruction below does not throw any exception that I can tell ? I have even tried defining a variable (wb) and assigning the open workbook and then explicitly closing !

Am I supposed to do an unload ? Is there something about the "GetObject" process I am missing ?

Any support appreciated

VBA Code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function getexternaldata(Filename As String, ProjectID As String, Column As Integer)
    ' modified version of taken from
    ' https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-sub-to-complete-vlookup-on-closed-file.1200205/
    
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim LookupRange As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
      
    With GetObject(Filename)
        Set LookupRange = Intersect(.Sheets("PPM Data extract").Range("A:CD"), .Sheets("PPM Data extract").UsedRange)
        getexternaldata = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ProjectID, LookupRange, Column, False)
        .Close (False)
    End With
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Item(2)
    wb.Close (False)
    
ErrHandler:
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

Comment: Well this `GetObject` opens the file as well. You cannot perform Excel function on a closed file. So why don't you just open the file hidden in the background so you are able to close it properly. That would be a good way to go.

Comment: Disable your `On Error Goto...` - it's probably hiding the problem.

Comment: You can fetch data from Excel using ADO / SQL without "opening" a file (of course, the file needs to be opened from the OS point of view, but at least the Excel UI is not affected)

Comment: If you're calling this function from a cell, it won't work. You need to use a separate instance of Excel.

Comment: Thanks eveyone for responding. FunThomas - I had done a littel ADO reserach but felt it was too far out of my depth. Would you be willing to provide a littl more support ? @Rory Can you explain why the function cannot be called from a cell ? Is there some context that the function call from within the cell cannot "see" hidden files to close ?

Comment: A function called from a cell should not be able to open a workbook in the same instance (`Getobject` seems to circumvent this limitation - `Workbooks.Open` will not work). It's one of many limitations as to what UDFs in cells can do.

Comment: I'd have thought using `ExecuteExcel4Macro` and passing a VLOOKUP formula in R1C1 format would be simpler and faster

Comment: @Rory Note that Microsoft disabled Excel 4 Macros by default with an update: https://twitter.com/GelosSnake/status/1446192775087722497

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Yes, but that doesn't affect the use of `ExecuteExcel4Macro` in code.

Comment: @Rory Ah good to know, thx for the update!

Answer (score 1):

### Using GetObject

- Note that this still opens the workbook but it is hidden.
- You cannot use this as a UDF.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub LookupExternalDataTEST()
    Const FilePath As String = "C:\Test\Test1.xlsx"
    Debug.Print LookupExternalData(FilePath, "Proj1", 2)
End Sub

Function LookupExternalData( _
    ByVal FilePath As String, _
    ByVal ProjectID As String, _
    ByVal ColumnNumber As Long) _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "LookupExternalData"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Const WorksheetName As String = "PPM Data extract"
    Const ColumnsAddress As String = "A:CD"
    
    With GetObject(FilePath)
        Dim LookupRange As Range
        With .Worksheets(WorksheetName)
            Set LookupRange = Intersect(.Range(ColumnsAddress), .UsedRange)
        End With
        LookupExternalData = Application.WorksheetFunction _
            .VLookup(ProjectID, LookupRange, ColumnNumber, False)
SafeExit:
        On Error Resume Next ' if file path error
            .Close SaveChanges:=False
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks eveyone for responding. FunThomas - I had done a littel ADO reserach but felt it was too far out of my depth. Would you be willing to provide a littl more support ? @Rory Can you explain why the function cannot be called from a cell ? Is there some context that the function call from within the cell cannot "see" hidden files to close ? I will try VBasic2008's suggestion but on a first pass I can't understand the difference in approach - especially given the call to clsoe the file is the same ? Thanks again everyone

Comment: Hi @VBasic2008 When I run the code in the debugger it fails at the "GetObject" call and does not hit the ClearError code ? You can see the file open in the VBA debugger window for a second but then it disappears ?

Comment: You have to feed the function valid parameters. If an error occurs, its number and description will be printed to the Immediate window (Ctrl+G) and you can act accordingly. You cannot use it as a UDF in an Excel cell.

Comment: Hi VBAsic2008, I opened the file in a separate instance of Excel and seems to be working. I am able to call the LookupExternalData function direct from the cell. Not sure why ? Do you know how I can open the workbook and avoid prompts such as update links as this stops the function ?

Comment: The second argument of the [Workbook.Open method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open) is `UpdateLinks`. You can also use the [Workbook.Updatelinks property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.updatelinks) to set it in the workbooks you're opening.